# SQL report based on specific criteria in monthly data

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Consider following data:

```
+-----+--------+----------+-------+
| Ref | Colour |  Month   | Value |
+-----+--------+----------+-------+
| 112 | Red    | January  |    16 |
| 113 | Black  | January  |    10 |
| 113 | Black  | January  |    11 |
| 112 | Yellow | February |    10 |
| 114 | Red    | February |     7 |
| 113 | Black  | February |    10 |
| 113 | Black  | February |    14 |
| 112 | Yellow | February |    15 |
| 113 | Black  | March    |     8 |
| 112 | Orange | March    |     1 |
| 114 | Blue   | April    |     6 |
| 113 | Black  | April    |     4 |
+-----+--------+----------+-------+
```

I'd like to query this table to produce a report that shows:

List of refs where colour = "black" in three last consecutive months -based on the sample data this will return 113.

Edit, I've had to simplify the original question.

Comment: do you need the intermediate result, or can it be a single query returning the pivot report?

Comment: The first part is actually more important for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have two parts to this -- pivoting the data and filtering for the last three months.  Probably the simplest method is to aggregate and then use `having`:

```
select ref,
       sum(case when month = 'January' then value else 0 end) as Jan,
       sum(case when month = 'February' then value else 0 end) as Feb,
       sum(case when month = 'March' then value else 0 end) as Mar,
       sum(case when month = 'April' then value else 0 end) as Apr
from t
where colour = 'Black'
group by ref
having sum(case when month = 'February' then value else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when month = 'March' then value else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when month = 'April' then value else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: If he has all months this query becames long. I wonder if there is something more concise.

Comment: I've simplified the original question, the first part is more important for me.